# how to create private cocoapods compatible for all swift 3.x versions?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods-1.1.1

I have created a private cocoapod in xcode 8.2(swift 3.0.2) using the tutorial as shown in the below link.
https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

cocoapod created successfully but the pod is compatible for only swift 3.0.2. If I try to use the pod in swift 3.0 or 3.1 it is saying module is compiled in swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in swift 3.0 or 3.1

IS there any solution to make the private pods compatible for all swift 3.x versions?

Comment: whats your min platform on cocoapods

Comment: @Anub 'ios 8.0'

Comment: try with 10.0 once

Comment: @Anub Thanks. I tried but still issue persists.

Comment: can you show your updated code

Comment: I changed minimum deployment target to 10.0

Comment: ok what the issue u ufaced

Comment: @Anub Thanks for ur suggestions. Again same problem, if the pod is compiled in swift 3.0.1 and I run in swift 3.1 i.e xcode 8.3.2 error saying module compiled in 3.0.1 cannot be imported in swift 3.1